# Program printing different co ordinates from the ones I generated for it

Tags: c, random, coordinates

Basically I need my program to place points I type in manually on a grid (which it does fine) and then place a point randomly on the same grid and repeat for as many times as user requests. Currently, my code prints the numbers computer selects but doesn't place them on grid until I type another number and press enter, where it then places it in a seemingly random place.
Here's my code

```
void placeCShip(){
    int a,b;
    srand(time(NULL));
    a = printf("%d\n", rand()%15);
    b = printf("%d\n", rand()%15);
    scanf("%d, %d", &a, &b);
    if (grid[a][b] == SEA, grid[a][b] != PSHIP){
        grid[a][b] = CSHIP;
    }
}
```

and this is the function that repeats it, it works perfectly fine when I exclude CShips and Pships still works when I include it, but Cships doesnt give correct co ordinates

```
void placePShips(){
    int i,fleetSize;
    printf("\nEnter fleet size : ");
    scanf("%d", &fleetSize);
    for(i=0;i<fleetSize;i++){
        placePShip();
        placeCShip();
        printGrid();
    }
}
```

What I've tried;

Removing printf altogether, and just using rand function, solves problem of telling me the random co ordinates but I still have to type another number and click enter for it to appear

full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAXGRIDSIZE 15
#define SEA '.'
#define PSHIP 'P'
#define CSHIP 'C'
#define BOMB '*'
#define SUNKENSHIP 'v'

unsigned char grid[MAXGRIDSIZE][MAXGRIDSIZE];


//F1
void printGrid(){
    int x, y;
    printf("\n");
    for(y=0; y<MAXGRIDSIZE; y++){
        printf("%2d", y);
        for(x=0; x<MAXGRIDSIZE; x++){
            printf("%3c", grid[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%2c", ' ');
    for(x=0; x<MAXGRIDSIZE; x++){
            printf("%3d", x);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//F2
void initGrid(){
    int x, y;
    for(y=0; y<MAXGRIDSIZE; y++){
        for(x=0; x<MAXGRIDSIZE; x++){
            grid[y][x] = SEA;
        }
    }
}

//F3
void placePShip(){
    int x,y;
    printf("\nEnter Ship location: x , y: ");
    scanf("%d , %d", &x, &y);
    if (grid[y][x] == SEA){
        grid[y][x] = PSHIP;
    }
}

//F4
void placeCShip(){
    int a,b;
    srand(time(NULL));
    a = rand()%15;
    b = rand()%15;
    scanf("%d, %d", &a, &b);
    if (grid[a][b] == SEA, grid[a][b] != PSHIP){
        grid[a][b] = CSHIP;
    }
}


//F5
void placePShips(){
    int i,fleetSize;
    printf("\nEnter fleet size : ");
    scanf("%d", &fleetSize);
    for(i=0;i<fleetSize;i++){
        placeCShip();
        placePShip();
        printGrid();
    }
}

//F6
int main(){
    initGrid();
    printGrid();
    placePShips();
    printGrid();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are more calls to `scanf()` in your code which you have not shown. Please make a [mre].

Comment: What is `SEA,`? ... I would expect to either have `&&` or `||` instead of that comma between the 2 checks in the condition.

Comment: @Yunnosch Added full code there, should be able to see everything now:)

Comment: @Yunnosch It works fine now except for everytime I enter co ordinates or fleetsize I have to type a character and enter for it to move to the next line/section of code

Comment: ;regarding the call to `srand()`.  That function should be called ONLY once, preferable at the beginning of the `main()` function

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`  )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: you have unwanted 'scanf' calls, which will

The code is mixing IO and typing. Consider reviewing each man page for each function before using it. Also, put attention to compiler warning, as this will save you lot of debugging time.

Starting with placeCShip:

```
void placeCShip(){
    // Loop until unused location is found.
    while ( 1 ) {
        int a=rand()%15 ;
        int b=rand()%10 ;
// MOVE to 'main':    srand(time(NULL));
        if (grid[a][b] == SEA){
            grid[a][b] = CSHIP;
            break ;
        }
    }
}
```

For Player ship, consider switch to fgets/sscanf. The 'scanf' will get you into infinite loop on parsing errors.

```
void placePShip(){
    // Loop until valid coordinates are entered.
    while ( 1 ) {
        int x,y;
        printf("\nEnter Ship location: x , y: ");
        scanf("%d , %d", &x, &y);
        if (grid[y][x] == SEA){
            grid[y][x] = PSHIP;
            break ;
       }
    }
}
```